# Rails 4 - Users are able to book spaces even if they back out of PayPal payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

So I have an e commerce type rails app where users are able to list spaces to be booked, and other users are able to book these spaces for a specified amount of time.

I used this tutorial, http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails, to set up my system.

Once a user submits a form to create a new booking, they are redirected to the PayPal website where they log in to paypal, confirm they are paying, and once they have paid they have an option to return to my website and see their booking invoice.

My issue is that when a user clicks submit on their new booking form and they are taken to the paypal website, they may press back on their browser, taking them back to my website, but their booking is now recorded.

How do I stop a booking from being recorded unless it has been paid for through paypal?

Here is my create action from my bookings controller:

```
def create
    @booking =  Booking.new(params[:booking].permit(booking_params)
    @booking.space = @space
    Space.find(@space.id).update_attributes( :balance => @space.balance + (@booking.length * @space.hourly_rate))
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @booking.paypal_url(space_booking_path(@space, @booking))
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Also my app/models/booking.rb:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
include Bookable

  def paypal_url(return_path)
  values = {
    business: "nikia.i-facilitator@peerparking.ca",
    cmd: "_xclick",
    upload: 1,
    return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
    invoice: id * rand(19284),
    amount: space.hourly_rate * length,
    item_name: space.address,
    item_number: space.id,
    quantity: '1',
    notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
  }
  "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end

end
```

And the relevant route in my routes.rb

```
post "spaces/:space_id/bookings/:id" => "bookings#show"
```

Answer (score 0):

A browser back-arrow should return to the URL at your site that the user was already at. This URL should not consider payment complete (and booking in order). Would hitting browser reload on your page that precedes the redirect to PayPal also allow the user to complete the booking?

Assuming you are using Website Payments Stnadard, you would normally process a booking only upon the user reaching the return_url that you provide to PayPal, and then your code successfully processing the result variables that PayPal will include in the post back to you. (Or for customers who pay but do not return to your site directly, you would use IPN to associate the payment to the customer's account so that their order can be fulfilled asynchronously.)